# Applying genetic algorithm in Random Forest Model in R

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, random-forest

I am New in R and i want to apply genetic algorithm for random Forest model and i am using (GA) package in R.my Code is

```
library(GA)

library(randomForest)

library(Hmisc)

data<-read.csv("norm.csv")

d=sort(sample(nrow(data),nrow(data)*.7))

train=data[d,]

test=data[-d,]

y<-train$Readmission

fitness <- function(string) {

  inc <- which(string == 1)

  x<- cbind(1, train[,inc])

  testing<-cbind(1,test[inc])

  mod<-randomForest(x,y)

  pr<-predict(mod,testing,type="raw")

  cst<-(somers2(pr,test$Readmission))


  return(cst)

}

GA <- ga("binary", fitness = fitness, nBits = ncol(train),
         names = colnames(train), monitor = plot,maxiter = 10)

plot(GA)

summary(GA)
```

how to analyze the solution....thanks..

Comment: Why don't you ask how to do feature selection using GA and evaluating using RF in R... Besides, I think this is so simple certainly someone did that already. Also you should probably use crossvalidation for RF. Does the performance of RF really depend so much on having the right features?

Comment: I just want to improve the c-statics(AUC) of randomforest Model.currently I am getting 0.69(AUC) but I need 0.75 please help me how improve the performance of random Forest..

Comment: You're asking how to do feature selection, but actually you want to improve classification accuracy. Feature selection may be a method to improve classification accuracy, but there may be others as well. You should search on the web and Google scholar and you will likely find some ideas in research papers that you can evaluate for your dataset.